# mongodb: group VS map-reduce VS aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to merge two collections, but I don't know how to do.

Should I use Group, MapReduce, Aggregation, or what?

**CONTENTS**

```
content_id
----------
1
2
3
```

**REACTIONS**

```
content_id     user
----------     ----
1              john
2              john
1              steve
2              steve
2              paul
```

How can I get a list of all contents and the count of users that reactioned for each one? something like this:

```
content_id       reactions
----------       ---------
1                2
2                3
3                0
```

Comment: If you want to merge two collections in an efficient way, MongoDB may not be the correct choice for you. It does not do joins.

Comment: thanks, I know this, but the data is already in mongo. for now I just need an ad hoc task

Comment: @user3175226 This is overly brief. How ad hoc? While I understand the tendency to to abstract. In general, abstract questions get abstract answers. If you don't say what you actually want in your question then do not blame the person that they did not respond with what you wanted. There are several different approaches. But you are not saying **exactly** what you are doing.

Comment: i'm just trying to collect statistics about the data I have in mongodb. merge two collections, as said in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the above data the most simple form is to use aggregate. You do not need to "merge" collections as the output you require can be obtained from using only one collection:

```js
db.reactions.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$content_id",
        "reactions": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

And of course that is much faster than trying to loop results in code.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Joachim and @Neil pointed out, your question is still abstract and your data doesn't seem to be modeled right.  If you had a valid reason to model it this way, then it's fine.

But if this is an adhoc task, you can try something like:

```js
> db.contents.find().forEach(function(doc) { 
... var count = db.reactions.find({content_id:doc._id}).count(); 
... print(doc._id + " - " + count) 
... })
1 - 2
2 - 3
3 - 0
```